# Recursive Hierarchical - Google BigQuery

Tags: graph, google-bigquery, common-table-expression, hierarchical-data, recursive-query

[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Faenh.jpg)

### [image]

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HYR1M.jpg)

[image]

Note: There are circular references and these must be stopped at the first "node" - Note: Stop.
As in the example output.

-There are cases where there are no "nodes" children, these are marked with Flag = 2, Note: End;

-There are cases where the "node" Father is also a child.

-For each entry ID, we want to apply this same logic. In the example of this output, case 1010 was used.

-The expected output can be a table, list, etc.

Tks.

Comment: *1010->1012->1013->1018->1015->1018->1015->stop* is a right path ? *1018* is a circular reference and shouldn't be stopped ?

Comment: Hi Jaytiger, tks for your comment, you're right, I'm sorry, the hierarchy should stop at the first "loop".
 
1010->1012->1013->1018->1015->1018->stop. This would be the right way. 

I don't know if I can edit the expected output image.

Comment: Done. I managed to fix the output table.

Comment: *1010->1012->1013->1018->1015->1020->STOP* has no cyclic reference and last `flag` is `1`.  Anyway I've written query based on my understading. Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below recursive approach.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE sample_table AS (
  -- put your *input* except *flag* here
), 
find_ends AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT t.*, IF(s.id IS NULL, true, false) AS ended
    FROM sample_table t
    LEFT JOIN sample_table s ON t.parent_id = s.id
),
iterations AS (
  SELECT id, parent_id, [id, parent_id] ids, id = parent_id duplicated, ended
    FROM find_ends WHERE id = '1010'
   UNION ALL
  SELECT t.id, t.parent_id,
         r.ids || [t.parent_id],
         t.parent_id IN UNNEST(r.ids),
         t.ended
    FROM iterations r JOIN find_ends t ON r.parent_id = t.id 
   WHERE duplicated IS FALSE AND r.ended IS FALSE
)
SELECT ids FROM iterations WHERE duplicated OR ended ORDER BY ARRAY_LENGTH(ids);
```

**Query results**

```
+---------------------------------------------+
|                     ids                     |
+---------------------------------------------+
| "[1010,3021]"                               |
| "[1010,3020]"                               |
| "[1010,1012,2021]"                          |
| "[1010,1012,2020]"                          |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1012]"                     |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,5020]"                |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1015,6020]"           |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1020,1020]"           |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1015,6021]"           |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1016,4022]"           |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1015,1018]"           |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1016,1018]"           |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1016,1010]"           |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1015,1016,1018]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1015,1020,1020]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1015,1016,1010]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1020,1015,1020]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1020,1015,1018]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1015,1016,4022]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1020,1015,6020]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1020,1015,6021]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1015,1020,1015]"      |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1020,1015,1016,1018]" |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1020,1015,1016,4022]" |
| "[1010,1012,1013,1018,1020,1015,1016,1010]" |
+---------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I didn't make it clear.  The information: end and stop, is not in the database, I put it as an explanatory note to stop the recursion.

Comment: You mean `flag` field is not a table column in your database ?

Comment: that's right, this column does not exist. I put it as an example of how recursion should stop.

Comment: I see, I'll revisit it later in my free time. By the way, the result except the flag is what you expect ?

Comment: thanks for your time and attention.  yes, the result of the table above is expected

Comment: the result needs to be like in the output table.

Comment: I've updated the answer without using `flag` infomation.